# What is the most efficient way to store world data for a 2D tile game?

Tags: java, 2d, data-structure, file-format

I'm working on a 2D tile based survival game for my programming class and as I was working on GUIs I realized that I would need an efficient way of storing and recalling not only the tile data and location as the world expands, but the active entities, their inventories, and the item data in said inventories.

What would be the best way to do this? Is there a specific file format or data structure that would be best? I get that my question is kind of vague but I'm stuck.

Comment: The answer is "Whatever suits your needs". Then _profile_ to find bottlenecks, _only then_ optimize.

Comment: Oh, and you did not specify what was your goal in making it "the most efficient". Space occupied, time taken, ease of use?

Comment: My bad. when it comes to efficiency, I'm looking for something that does what I need with the least amount of overhead.

Comment: Overhead... computationally when using it or to make it work?

Comment: Yeah which overhead. There are lots of types of overhead.

Comment: When the game is run. Making it require as little computer resources as possible.

Comment: Well back to square one. See my first comment. You're not having an issue with your resource usage yet. You'll encounter more important issues to tackle before that: rendering, AI, physics. Make something that works first, then fix the issues that profiling highlighted.

Comment: How are you stuck exactly?  What are you currently doing?  Why is it not working for you?

Comment: A UTF text file. No, for real, it is generally better to write a simple parser for your map files or to use an existing framework for them. LibGdx supports a format of tiled maps. Since you only have to load before levels and in between them, performance isnt a big issue. A simple, but not necessarily the most resource efficient approach is something like [this](http://pastebin.com/D9CbfXZs) that I wrote as an example and it will work most fine unless you have thousands upon thousands of tiles, in which case this is insanely easy to optimize ;)